# Creating a number pattern based on the length of an array

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, octave

Creating a number pattern based on the length of array, the example is small just showing what it would look like if the array had a size of 5,6 or 7. (the actually length of arrays will be around 400,000)

How can I go about getting this numerical pattern.  I was thinking it looked a little like Pascal's Triangle but the numbers are off.

I'm using **Octave 3.8.1** which is like Matlab

---

example: If an array has the length of 5 the series would be

```
a1=[1 1 1;1 2 2;1 2 3;1 2 2;1 1 1]
a2=[1 1 1;2 2 1;3 2 1;2 2 1;1 1 1]
```

example: If an array has the length of 6 the series would be

```
a1=[1 1 1;1 2 2;1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 2;1 1 1]
a2=[1 1 1;2 2 1;3 2 1;3 2 1;2 2 1;1 1 1]
```

example: If an array has the length of 7 the series would be

```
a1=[1 1 1 1;1 2 2 2;1 2 3 3;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 3;1 2 2 2;1 1 1 1]
a2=[1 1 1 1;2 2 2 1;3 3 2 1;4 3 2 1;3 3 2 1;2 2 2 1;1 1 1 1]
```

See image below: 
[image: Image of number pattern going up and going down]

Comment: Have you had a look at [`bwdist`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) already? It requires the image processing toolbox though.

Comment: Will it always be 3 columns? It seems that after 6 rows you only need to insert `[3,2,1]` or `[1,2,3]` resp., in between.

Comment: What's the pattern? Why two output variables?

Comment: @knedlsepp no it won't always be three columns I'll update the question now.  Thanks

Comment: @Luis Mendo it's counting up then down by rows.  I'll add a picture also

Comment: @LuisMendo The two output variables are: a1 is the pattern and a2 is the pattern "reversed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be quite fast:

```
n = 9;

a1 = bsxfun(@min, min(1:n,n:-1:1).', 1:ceil(n/2));
a2 = a1(:,end:-1:1);
```

Comment: I was about to write the same +1, but according to the OPs request I would include at the beginning `m = 6;
n = ceil(m/2)` where `m` is the actual input of the OP. (so may swap `n` and `m`)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Added your improvement.

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want:

```
n = 7;
a1 = cumsum(tril(ones(ceil(n/2))), 2);
a1 = a1([1:end end-mod(n,2):-1:1],:);
a2 = fliplr(a1);
```

Answer (score 3):

A slighty different approach:

For `m = ceil(n/2);` the `bsxfun` can be substituted by

```
X = gallery('minij',m);
```

which is equal to:

```
X = bsxfun(@min, 1:m,(1:m).')
```

so you get a single block and you just need to concatenate the output.

```
a1 = [X; flipud(X)]
if n ~= 2*m; a1(m,:) = []; end  %// clear one row if necessary
a2 = fliplr(a1)
```

---

for `n = 6` you get

```
a1 =
     1     1     1
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     2
     1     1     1
```

and `a2` accordingly mirrored. and for `n = 5`

```
a1 =
     1     1     1
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     2     2
     1     1     1
```

Comment: +1. Just generating the top and then flipping will probably be slightly faster than a `bsxfun` for the entire thing (as in my approach).

Comment: @knedlsepp not necessarily, depends on how the gallery function is internally working.

Comment: `gallery` keeps surprising me!

Comment: Ok. The single `bsxfun` is really actually faster, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Octave has `gallery` since 3.8.0.  That function in Matlab is mostly based on Nicholas .J. Higham's test matrix toolbox (predecessor to his [Matrix computation toolbox](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/mctoolbox/))from the early 90's and is released under GPL.

Comment: thought that maybe you'd like to now I [reused](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/941e782d0429) this for octave's gallery, and indeed it is faster now